# Identical View Controllers Displaying Differently

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two child view controllers, that as far as I can tell are identical, however one of them is acting unexpectedly.

The two child view controllers are called `MenuLoggedInViewController` and `MenuLoggedOutViewController`. Their container view controller has the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // i comment out one of these two lines to produce the different results:
    self.masterView = MenuLoggedOutViewController(nibName: "MenuLoggedOutViewController", bundle: nil)
    // self.masterView = MenuLoggedInViewController(nibName: "MenuLoggedInViewController", bundle: nil)

    self.detailView = RootViewController(nibName: "RootViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.masterViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 50)
    self.detailViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 50)
    self.addChildViewController(masterView!)
    self.addChildViewController(detailView!)
    self.view.addSubview(masterView!.view)
    self.view.addSubview(detailView!.view)

    masterView!.view.frame = masterViewFrame
    // masterView!.view.bounds = masterViewFrame // - i tried this and it made no difference
    detailView!.view.frame = detailViewFrame
}
```

The `MenuLoggedInViewController` and `MenuLoggedOutViewController` have pretty much identical template code in their swift files:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

I have not touched the `.xib` files except to change the background colour. After going through the settings for the `.xib` files they *seem* to all be the same. I don't go near the storyboard if I can help it, so I am not too familiar with it. But I spent a long time double checking all the values for the two `.xib` files and there is no difference between them that I can detect other than the background colour.

[image: <code>MenuLoggedInViewController</code> produces this:]

As you can see, the black `MenuLoggedInViewController` fits snuggly against the white view controller beneath. This is intended.

[image: <code>MenuLoggedOutViewController</code> produces this:]

The grey background is the colour of the containing view controller. As you can see the black `MenuLoggedOutViewController` only goes so far down.

Can anyone explain to me, despite being virtually identical and called with virtually identical code, why the `MenuLoggedOutViewController` doesn't display properly?

It should be noted that `MenuLoggedOutViewController` corrects itself if the screen is rotated to the side and then back again to portrait. Then `MenuLoggedOutViewController` looks like it should (like `MenuLoggedInViewController`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell precisely what is going on. If you really want, I'd suggest using `NSStringFromCGRect` and examining the various `frame` values and I suspect you'd see what's going on.

But the key conceptual problem is that this code is adjusting the `frame` values in `viewDidLoad`, but the `frame` value is not reliable at that point. I'd suggest either:

- Move the adjustment of child `frame` values to `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. At that point, the main view's `frame` is reliable.
- If using auto-layout, don't set the `frame` values at all, but rather set `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` for these two child views and then add constraints (which you can do in `viewDidLoad`), whose VFL would effectively be:

  ```
  V:|[master(50)][detail]|
  H:|[master]|
  H:|[detail]|
  ```

---

As a final, unrelated detail, when calling `addChildViewController`, after you're done adding the child views, don't forget to call `didMoveToParentViewController` for each of those child view controllers.

Comment: Excellent - i put my framing code in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and it all works fine now! Many thanks - and thanks for the tip about `didMoveToParentViewController` - totally forgot to add that!